# iOS today extension target membership of container classes or userdefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I have an iOS app that also has a today extension. I am trying to feed the today extension data from the main container application but have a lot of decodable model classes that are used to hold data.

My questions are:

1. Is it better to use userDefaults to get/set the data from container
   into the extension or include the today extension target in all of
   the model classes?
2. Does including a lot of classes in the todayExtension target cause
       performance issues or battery drain or anything like that?

Thanks.

*EDIT
An example of my model class is:

```
class Alert : Codable {
var type : String?
var sequence : Int?
var status : String?
var issueTimeText : String?
var expiryTime : String?
var alertId : String?
var alertBannerText : String?
var alertHeaderText : String?
var bannerColour : String?
var zones : [String]?
// TEXT IS [STRING], STRING FOR TESTING
var text : String?
var tcisURL : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case type = "type";
    case sequence = "sequence";
    case status = "status";
    case issueTimeText = "issueTimeText";
    case expiryTime = "expiryTime";
    case alertId = "alertId";
    case alertBannerText = "alertBannerText";
    case alertHeaderText = "alertHeaderText";
    case bannerColour = "bannerColour";
    case text = "text";
    case zones = "zones";
    case tcisURL = "tcisURL";
}

init(inType: String, inIssueTimeText:String, inBannerText:String, inText: String, inColor: String) {
    self.type = inType
    self.issueTimeText = inIssueTimeText
    self.alertBannerText = inBannerText
    self.text = inText;
    self.bannerColour = inColor
}
```

Comment: What kind of data are you storing? How much of it? Can you post an example of your data model that you're referring to?

Comment: " include the today extension target in all of the model classes?" what does that mean? You can't include a target in a class. I think you are mixing up terminology or confusing concepts.  When including things in an extension there are two things you need to be aware of: 1) there is limited memory available compared to an app 2) Not all frameworks/headers etc. that can be included in an app can be included in an extension.

Comment: @Gruntcakes I meant for each of the model classes, include the todayExtension as a part of the target membership (ie checkboxes that indicate what class is 'visible' to what target). Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jake please see the edit. They are all just simple structs that conform to Codable

Comment: Is the goal to save a history of alerts to the device?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you want the data to go in to the today extension. Yes I have found that user defaults is the best. You will have to create app groups both in the app and today extension. That how the user defaults work with a today extension. So when you want to save the data to the user defaults(either by a button or updating timer) you will need this code `UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.bundleID.appName")?.setValue(textfield.text, forKey: "name")`

So that is how it is saved. In your today extension under the `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` you need to retrieve the data and put it on a label so write this code. `if let name = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.bundleID.appName")?.value(forKey: "name")
{
    label.text = name as? String
}`
It should work. I also have a video on YouTube on this exact tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skbWSQlcN5k

Hope this helps, Nathan

Comment: Thanks for your response and suggestion. This is currently how I am doing it but was just wondering if its a bad idea to include a bunch of model classes as a target member of the today extension.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm assuming you want to save a history of alerts to the device.**

You don't want to use `UserDefaults` for this.

If my assumption is correct, you would be better off using Core Data to store the data to your device and retrieve it for later use. Core data is a resource that will allow you to store data to your device and to a database if you wish. There is too much to discuss here but [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2) has a great blog that will walk you through this and many other things.